# Permissions of uploaded files in /var/www

Tags: php, apache, web

I have a picture folder in the website directory and every time i upload pictures into that directory, they have the wrong permissions and i have to manually change the permissions so that i could alter the images or rotate them, delete, copy etc. Is there a way to automatically change the permissions of the uploaded files in that specific folder. May be there is some permission field in Apache configurations that can be changed. Please help!
Thank you.

Comment: Create a folder inside `/var/www` and give that folder read write permission recursive.

Answer (score 3):

Most likely the user running the webapp is www-data (for ubuntu/debian based OS). If the user you are logging in to your box is a different, the best you can do is to setup a group and make that group own `/var/www` - or only the folder you really need. The group should hold the both users:

add a group:

```
sudo groupadd <name of the group> // whatever you prefer
```

Now that the group exists, add the two users to it:

```
sudo usermod -a -G usergroup <your username> // the one you login with
sudo usermod -a -G usergroup www-data
```

Now all that's left is to set the permissions on the directory:

```
sudo chgrp -R usergroup /var/www
sudo chmod -R 775 /var/www
```

Now only members of the usergroup group can read, write, or execute files and folders within the directory. Note the -R argument to the chmod and chgrp commands: this tells them to recurse into every sub directory of the target directory and modify every file and directory available.

**Please note** that group assignment changes won't take effect until the users log out and back in.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `chmod` in PHP to change the permissions.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.chmod.php